# How to use time stamp as parameter in stored procedure

Tags: oracle

created a stored procedure with timestamp as parameter

when inserting data into that procedure

getting error like ORA-01843: not a valid month

how to resolve this error?

can any one explain me how to pass time stamp as parameter in stored procedure with format 'MM-DD-YYYY'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GETDETAILS(CUST_ID NUMBER,PROJECT_NAME NVARCHAR2,CREATED_DATE TIMESTAMP) AS 
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO RDATA_TABLE VALUES(CUST_ID,PROJECT_NAME,TO_TIMESTAMP(CREATED_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY')); 
END;

EXECUTE GETDETAILS(11,'PEP','03-22-2021'
```

Comment: You don't even show how you call your procedure...

Comment: Timestamps don't have an intrinsic format. It sounds like you're passing a string instead of an actual timestamp when you call the procedure. It would help if you included how you're calling it, at least.

Answer (score 0):

> can any one explain me how to pass time stamp as parameter in stored procedure with format 'MM-DD-YYYY'

You do not. A `TIMESTAMP` is a binary data format consisting of 7-20 bytes (century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute, second, up to 6 bytes for fractional seconds and up to 7 bytes for time zone information); it does not have a format.

If you want to create a procedure that takes a `TIMESTAMP` argument then just use:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name (
  i_timestamp IN TIMESTAMP
)
IS
BEGIN
  NULL;
END procedure_name;
/
```

If you want to pass a timestamp then use a timestamp literal:

```sql
BEGIN
  procedure_name( TIMESTAMP '2021-03-22 12:34:56' );
END;
/
```

Or use the `TO_TIMESTAMP` function to convert a string literal (with a format) to a `TIMESTAMP` data type (without a format):

```sql
BEGIN
  procedure_name( TO_TIMESTAMP( '03-22-2021', 'MM-DD-YYYY' ) );
END;
/
```

Comment: This is the procedure i am using

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE GETDETAILS(CUST_ID NUMBER,PROJECT_NAME NVARCHAR2,CREATED_DATE TIMESTAMP) 
AS 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO RDATA_TABLE VALUES(CUST_ID,PROJECT_NAME,TO_TIMESTAMP(CREATED_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY')); 
END
EXECUTE GETDETAILS(11,'PEP','03-22-2021')
This is the procedure i am using and gave execute command  also 
error is not a valid month

Comment: @chandra Your value in the procedure is already a `TIMESTAMP` you do not need to call `TO_TIMESTAMP` on it. Just use `INSERT INTO RDATA_TABLE VALUES(CUST_ID,PROJECT_NAME,CREATED_DATE);` When you call the procedure, then you need to convert it from a string to a timestamp `EXECUTE GETDETAILS(11,'PEP', TO_TIMESTAMP( '03-22-2021', 'MM-DD-YYYY' ) );`

Comment: tried using this EXECUTE GETDETAILS(11,'PEP', TO_TIMESTAMP( '03-22-2021', 'MM-DD-YYYY' ) ); to execute procedure, getting same error not a valid month ,but when i pass current_timestamp as parameter it is working

Comment: @chandra Did you make both changes that I'd mentioned in my previous comment or only the second change?

Comment: changed in both

Comment: @chandra [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1ad3be02098f304dc441b1a1f9bb11fd) works for me.

Comment: changed stored procedure and tried again it is working thank you so much for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Running `TO_TIMESTAMP()` on a value which is already a `TIMESTAMP` does not make much sense.

Your procedure expects a `TIMESTAMP` value but you provide a string. Give a `TIMESTAMP` as input value.

In summary it would be this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GETDETAILS(CUST_ID NUMBER, PROJECT_NAME NVARCHAR2, CREATED_DATE TIMESTAMP) AS 
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO RDATA_TABLE VALUES(CUST_ID, PROJECT_NAME, CREATED_DATE); 
END;

EXECUTE GETDETAILS(11,'PEP',TO_TIMESTAMP('03-22-2021', 'MM-DD-YYYY'));
```

or use timestamp literals:

```
GETDETAILS(11,'PEP', TIMESTAMP '2021-03-22 00:00:00')
```

NB, procedure name "**Get**Details" is a bit misleading, the procedure does not retrieve any details, it makes an insert.

Why do you use `NVARCHAR2`?  In 2021 there is no reason anymore to use it, since usually databases runs on UTF-8 nowadays.